# Sitecore page editor dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, enums, sitecore, page-editor

I would kindly ask for your help :) From couple of days I am trying to achieve "linked" custom field in content editor and dropdown in page editor. 
Basically I want to have dropdown in page editor and content editor which are responsible for a same thing.

In my c# code i have enums which represent directions. I created custom field which accepts assembly and class with overridden onload method and successfully populate dropdown values in the content editor. So far so good but i have no idea how to create dropdown which will represent the same functionality inside page editor.
So please give me any ideas...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you are trying 2 things: 1 adding a custom field type to sitecore and 2 having that custom field show up as a dropdown in page editor mode. If I understand correctly you succeeded in part 1 but are struggling with part 2 right?

Comment: Yes. I successfully created the custom field. As you said in part 2 I am trying to do the same thing in page editor. I think that a possible solution might be creating page editor component which i hove no clue how to do :)

Comment: I think this question deals with far too big a topic to be answered here. I suggest reading the Presentation Component 
Reference before you attempt to continue http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/presentation_component_reference-a4.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your reply to my comment you need to think of the following: **How is my field value being rendered onto a page?**

If you are always using 1 control to do this then you just need to ensure that this control has 2 different rendering modes depending on the Context.PageMode

But as I understand it you want this dropdown to also appear when someone renders your custom field using a `<sc:FieldRenderer>`. In this case you'll need to look into the **RenderField** pipeline of Sitecore. There you find a processor called **RenderWebEditing**. Possibly through some manipulation here you can get your dropdown appear as you wish.